# CentOS 5.5 - Disk Filling Up With No Known Cause

Tags: nfs, centos5, disk-space-utilization

I have a CentOS 5.5 box with a seperate partition for /home. `df -h` shows it at 100% usage. `df -i` shows tons of free inodes. `du -sh /home /home*` shows that there are about 100MB worth of files in /home. lsof -n|grep /home shows no open files in /home. lsof -n|grep deleted shows no files touching /home.

The partition is shared out via NFS and is mounted on two other CentOS 5.5 clients. `lsof -n|grep /home` and `lsof -n|grep deleted` show no files for for `/home` or `/`.

When I unmount and remount the partition, disk usage drops from 100% to less than 3%. However the disk usage is back at 100% within a few days.

The only things using /home are NFSd, a custom script, and SSHd. This script moves files from `/home/somedir` to `/home/tmp`, then moves the files to /tmp, then parses the files. This script runs on all three boxes.

New files are placed in /home by a script that SCPs the files into a chroot envoriment setup in `/home`. Only a couple binaries plus a `/dev/null` node are in `/home/somepath/...`.

I have used `service nfs stop` and `service portmap stop` to stop nfs, stopped sshd, validated that the script mentioned above isn't running, and then checked disk usage. It remains at 100%. Only unmounting and remounting it seems to clear it up.

An fsck -f of /home (while unmounted of course) shows that the file system is fine.

All boxes are fully updated and running CentOS 5.5.

Where is my disk space going?

Comment: Is this NFSv3 or NFSv4?

Comment: NFSv4 I think. Whatever the default is for CentOS 5.

Comment: Turns out it was using v3. Trying v4 now...

Comment: No change when switching to v4 only - Still getting ever increasing disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

Speculation: your custom script, running on all three boxes, is tripping over the other instances of itself while trying to manipulate the same files from three places; NFS client running on the remote system tells its kernel that it has deleted a file, but it's actually been deleted by a process on another system in the interim, so the remote client gets stuck.

Solution: Use NFS to allow the remote systems to access the filesystem, but only run the cleanup script on the exporting system.

Comment: Possible. I'll try changing the mounts from async to sync. Since the whole move from /home/somedir to /home/tmp is to have an "atomic operation" that (at least probably) won't happen at the exact moment on all three boxes...well...i was hoping that would do. But perhaps not.